# VBA unprotect cells according to colorindex - run time error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to the forum but have to admit I've used VBA code from this forum on many occasions. It's a great resource. However I have been unable to get my latest code to run properly. PS My VBA skills are limited.

My problem:

I have several identically formatted worksheets within a workbook. Columns in the worksheets are either classified as "actual" data or "forecast" data. Cells in the "forecast" column are conditionally formatted to be yellow (color index 36).

What I want to do is to lock every cell in the used range on each sheet that isn't yellow to prevent users from changing cells that contain actual data.

I borrowed the code below and made some tweaks - I can step through without issues but when I run it fully a get the 1004 run time error. I suspect it's something to do with protecting the sheets. I did have the code set to run for each sheet in the workbook but have changed it to "activesheet" to try and isolate the problem.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LockExceptYellowCells()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex <> 36 Then
        c.Locked = True
        Else
        c.Locked = False
        End If

    Next c

    ActiveSheet.Protect

End Sub
```

Comment: which line raises the error?

Comment: FYI the whole `IF..ELSE..END IF` can be replaced with `c.Locked = c.Interior.ColorIndex <> 36`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping your variables and sheets the way they are, I cleaned up the code and added the "For Each Worksheet" back into it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LockExceptYellowCells()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Unprotect
        For Each c In ws.UsedRange
           c.Locked = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> 36
        Next c
    ws.Protect
Next ws

End Sub
```

I tested this with the same color index and it goes through each sheet.  It first unprotects the sheet, does the check, and protects it based on the color index.  Then it will go to the next sheet.

If this still does not work, then try this instead:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LockExceptYellowCells()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Unprotect
Next ws

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each c In ws.UsedRange
       c.Locked = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> 36
    Next c
    ws.Protect
Next ws

End Sub
```

This *should not* make a difference, but what this does is it goes through and unprotects each sheet first, then goes through and does the color protection.

Comment: Vityata and Busse, thanks for the prompt replies. Both sets of code fell over so I copied a single sheet from my workbook to a new file and ran again. It still fell over. I think part of the reason is I have merged cells - I unmerged these and the code worked when I manually coloured a cell yellow. However for conditionally formatted cells it still didn't work - i suspect it's because the underlying colorindex is 0 and not 36. It only changes to 36 when a condition is met.

Comment: @Gormat, I have an idea if it's Conditional Formatting.  Instead of doing `c.Interior.ColorIndex <> 36`

try:

`c.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> 36`

I tested the color index of conditional formatted fields and I was getting ridiculous results.  When using DisplayFormat prior to Interior it is displaying correct results.  Test it out by selecting one of the conditional cells with the color index of 36, and run a quick `MsgBox ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex` and it will tell you the color index.

I have updated my original answer with DisplayFormat

Comment: It works - thank you. Can I confirm that merged cells are a no no. It isn't a big issue since the merged cells don't appear in the data range. I will just have to change from usedrange to a specified range if I want to continue using merged cells.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and it works for me, on an empty sheet. Try it as well, the problem should be somewhere else:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LockExceptYellowCells()

    Dim c As Range

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect "pesho"

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        c.Locked = c.Interior.ColorIndex <> 36
    Next c

    ActiveSheet.Protect "pesho"

End Sub
```

In general, if you can exclude `True` and `False` and `if` but give a condition instead, the code is more understandable.

Comment: Good call on removing the If Elses.